# LTS 12.04 update NVIDIA driver 319.32 reconfigured not able to get past login screen

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg, login-screen

I've encountered a similar problem as 
[Nvidia driver updated - mixed versions of 304.88 and 319.32](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342664/nvidia-driver-updated-mixed-versions-of-304-88-and-319-32)
and
[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - Black Screen at boot After changing Nvidia Driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328551/ubuntu-12-04-lts-black-screen-at-boot-after-changing-nvidia-driver)

Using what I found there, I was able to purge the nvidia version 304 and reconfigure version 319. Now my problem is that I can get to the login screen for unity, but I can't get past this screen. I enter my password and I just here the drum sound and the login screen comes up again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem --> https://askubuntu.com/questions/351268/nvidia-driver-updated-mixed-versions-of-304-88-and-319-32-tried-saurav-kumar-f

but you only need to give ownership of Xorg back to your account as all the installs were done by root - that should solve your troubles.

simply boot into terminal (ctrl+alt+f3 in the login screen) login and write

```
sudo chown username:username .Xauthority
```

hope it helps

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with lightdm, kept looping me back to the login screen. I've switched to gdm and things are running fine.

Comment: if gdm is fine for you stay with it ;-) if not a remove/install lightdm might do the trick as well